# AngularJS bootstrap datepicker - day in week issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS bootstrap datepicker. I am trying to format the "day in week" to show only the first letter, not three.
Here is a screenshot of the calendar:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4owa7.jpg
I only managed to make it show the entire word, or the first three letters.
HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="sell_date_start" id="sell_date_start" class="form-control" datepicker-popup='MM/dd/yyyy' ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened1" min-date="minDate" close-text="Close" ng-click="open($event,'opened1')" readonly />
```

JS:

```
    .config(function (datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig) {
        datepickerConfig.formatDayHeader = 'EEE';
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a bit of code here that is in question.

Answer (score 1):

It uses Angular's date filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Unfortunately, there is no option there for a single letter 'day in week.'

You could potentially provide your own template for the datepicker that adds an additional filter to limitTo one character.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use CSS to display only the first letter of the 3 letter string.

For example the following HTML:

```
<div class="day-of-the-week">
    Sun
</div>
```

Could be styled as such with CSS:

```
div.day-of-the-week {
    font-size: 0;
}

div.day-of-the-week:first-letter {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Please note that the :first-letter psuedo selector only applies to block level elements.

See more about this selector here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp